# sorting the score calculated from the program

Tags: java

```
int queryVector = 1;
    double similarity = 0.0;
    int wordPower;
    String[][] arrays = new String[filename][2];
    int row;
    int col;


    for (a = 0; a < filename; a++) {
        int totalwordPower = 0;
        int totalWords = 0;
        try {
            System.out
                    .println(" _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _  ");
            System.out.println("\n");
            System.out.println("The word inputted : " + word2);
            File file = new File(
                    "C:\\Users\\user\\fypworkspace\\TextRenderer\\abc" + a
                            + ".txt");
            System.out.println(" _________________");

            System.out.print("| File = abc" + a + ".txt | \t\t \n");

            for (int i = 0; i < array2.length; i++) {

                totalCount = 0;
                wordCount = 0;

                Scanner s = new Scanner(file);
                {
                    while (s.hasNext()) {
                        totalCount++;
                        if (s.next().equals(array2[i]))
                            wordCount++;

                    }

                    System.out.print(array2[i] + " --> Word count =  "
                            + "\t " + "|" + wordCount + "|");
                    System.out.print("  Total count = " + "\t " + "|"
                            + totalCount + "|");
                    System.out.printf("  Term Frequency =  | %8.4f |",
                            (double) wordCount / totalCount);

                    System.out.println("\t ");

                    double inverseTF = Math.log10((float) numDoc
                            / (numofDoc[i]));
                    System.out.println("    --> IDF = " + inverseTF);

                    double TFIDF = (((double) wordCount / totalCount) * inverseTF);
                    System.out.println("    --> TF/IDF = " + TFIDF + "\n");

                    totalWords += wordCount;

                    wordPower = (int) Math.pow(wordCount, 2);

                    totalwordPower += wordPower;

                    System.out.println("Document Vector : " + wordPower);

                    similarity = (totalWords * queryVector)
                            / ((Math.sqrt((totalwordPower)) * (Math
                                    .sqrt(((queryVector * 3))))));



                }
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("File is not found");
        }
        System.out.println("The total query frequency for this file is "
                + totalWords);
        System.out.println("The total document vector : " + totalwordPower);

        System.out.println("The similarity is " + similarity);
    }
}
```

}

Hi i wanted to sort the SIMILARITY SCORE calculated from the code above. This is an example output of 2 text files. I have total of 10 text files together.

The word inputted : how are you

---

| File = abc0.txt |
how --> Word count =     |0|  Total count =      |1289|  Term Frequency =  |   0.0000 |
    --> IDF = 1.0413926851582251
    --> TF/IDF = 0.0

Document Vector : 0
are --> Word count =     |0|  Total count =      |1289|  Term Frequency =  |   0.0000 |
    --> IDF = 0.43933269383026263
    --> TF/IDF = 0.0

Document Vector : 0
you --> Word count =     |0|  Total count =      |1289|  Term Frequency =  |   0.0000 |
    --> IDF = 0.1962946357308887
    --> TF/IDF = 0.0

Document Vector : 0
The total query frequency for this file is 0
The total document vector : 0
The SIMILARITY is NaN

---

The word inputted : how are you

---

| File = abc1.txt |
how --> Word count =     |0|  Total count =      |426|  Term Frequency =  |   0.0000 |
    --> IDF = 1.0413926851582251
    --> TF/IDF = 0.0

Document Vector : 0
are --> Word count =     |0|  Total count =      |426|  Term Frequency =  |   0.0000 |
    --> IDF = 0.43933269383026263
    --> TF/IDF = 0.0

Document Vector : 0
you --> Word count =     |3|  Total count =      |426|  Term Frequency =  |   0.0070 |
    --> IDF = 0.1962946357308887
    --> TF/IDF = 0.0013823565896541458

Document Vector : 9
The total query frequency for this file is 3
The total document vector : 9
The SIMILARITY is 0.5773502691896257

Note : This is example run of two text files. I have a total of 10 text files.

How to sort the SIMILARITY score from the highest to the lowest? Any advices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the SIMILARITY scores to a list and sort using library method. It sorts in ascending order, you can read it from the end.

```
ArrayList<Double> arrayList = new ArrayList<Double>();
Collections.sort(arrayList);
```

Or you can declare a Comparator and use it like below.

```
ArrayList<Double> arrayList = new ArrayList<Double>();
Comparator<Double> comparator = Collections.reverseOrder();
Collections.sort(arrayList,comparator);
```

HTH